# Unicode with accents raising UnicodeDecodeError on logging (App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to make a change to an old appengine application, but now after formating my pc and installing updated tools the logging functions are raising a unicode error.

In the previous development environment everything worked fine.
    ubuntu 9.04
    python2.6
    google appengine sdk 1.5

Now I'm trying make a change using this environment:
    ubuntu 11.10
    python2.7
    google appengine sdk 1.6

In this new development environment I'm getting errors using logging functions.

```
logging.info(u'Gerando lista de exibição') # error
```

Error:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
>         args = ('ascii', 'Gerando lista de exibi\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o', 22, 23, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
>        encoding = 'ascii'
>        end = 23
>        message = ''
>        object = 'Gerando lista de exibi\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o...'
>        reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)'
>        start = 22

To work I need remove accents:

> logging.info(u'Gerando lista de exibicao') # ok

My editor is utf-8 and all my scripts have "coding: utf-8" as first line.

This is a version problem? There is some settings to do?

Comment: Can you get a stack trace for where that error is raised? It should be fine to send a Unicode string to a `Logger` instance. Looking at the GAE code, it should be attempting to UTF-8-encode that string and then write it to the handler stream, `stderr` by default. However the error makes it look like something is trying to convert the UTF-8 bytes back into Unicode (and using the default encoding). Is it possible something is sitting on top of `stderr` and hacking it to use Unicode instead of normal bytes?

Comment: I don't have a stack trace now, but I always use unicode strings on django, appengine e any logging functions and neve had problems.
But I discoved that is a bug on app engine. See my answers above [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107388/unicode-with-accents-raising-unicodedecodeerror-on-logging-app-engine/8112992#8112992)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6266

Hopefully it will be corrected in next version (1.6.1).

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking this page on [unicode and utf-8](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) encoding. Strategies and workaround are also included. It's a known issue since Python 2 default encoding is 'ascii'.

Answer (score -1):

Python 2 is not using UTF-8 by default for source code, otherwise you will have to specify the encoding. See [PEP-263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Anyway, it's not a good idea to keep Unicode in your source code.

Comment: as I said:
*My editor is utf-8 and all my scripts have "coding: utf-8" as first line*

Comment: I'm not using unicode in source code, is utf-8 and all strings are unicode objects.

Comment: The code is real utf-8, but all strings is unicode objects. (Well, I don't know how explain that, anyway is a bug on app engine.)